# For a subgroup $H \leq G$, establish a relation between $Z_{i}(G)$ and $Z_{i}(H)$

Tags: group-theory

Considering $Z(H)$ and $Z(G)$ (case $i = 1$), I believe $Z(H) \supseteq Z(G) \cap H$, because there could be elements of $H$ that commute with all of $H$ but not all of $G$. Can something stronger be said? And for $i > 1$, I have no intuition what's going on with $Z_i(G)$ or $Z_i(H)$ with the definition of an upper central series, so I have no idea how to go about proving any relation...

I used the second isomorphism theorem on $Z(G) \trianglelefteq G$ and $H$, for

$$(HZ(G))/Z(G) \cong H/(H \cap Z(G))$$

And if I'm not mistaken $(HZ(G))/Z(G) = H/Z(G)$, because for an element $hg \in HZ(G)$, the left coset $hgZ(G) = hZ(G)$. But I'm not sure where to go from here.

Comment: You are mistaken if $Z(G)$ is not $\le H$

Comment: @HagenvonEitzen If $Z(G)$ is not $\leq H$, I can see that $HZ(G) \neq H$. But I'm not confident what's going on when taking the quotient group with respect to $Z(G)$. Where did I go wrong in my argument about the cosets?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I believe the relation is:

$$Z_i(G) \cap H \leq Z_i(H)$$

Clearly for $i = 1$, $Z(G)$ centralizes everything, so a subset of it (the elements also belonging to $H$) centralizes all of $H$. The intersection of subgroups is a subgroup, and it is contained in $H$, so it is a subgroup of $H$.

---

Lemma: Let $g, h \in G$. Let $A$, $B$ be subgroups of $G$, $A \leq B$. Then if the cosets $gA = hA$, then $gB = hB$.

Proof: $h^{-1}gA = 1A$ so $h^{-1}g \in A \leq B$. So $h^{-1}gB = 1B$ and $gB = hB$. Intuitively, if we have coset equality, we can make it "bigger".

---

Now by induction, assuming the relation and proving for $i + 1$.

Let $g_1 \in Z_{i + 1}$. By the definition:

$$Z_{i + 1}(G)/Z_i(G) = Z(G / Z_i(G))$$

For all $g_2 \in G$, $g_{1}g_{2}g_{1}^{-1}Z_i(G) = g_2Z_i(G)$.

This still holds if we restrict $g_1$ and $g_2$ to $H$. Starting from any side of the equality, if we restrict $Z_i(G)$ to $Z_i(G) \cap H$, we can do the same on the other side, because on one side we will have the product of elements in $H$. On the other side, we have either $g_{1}g_{2}g_{1}^{-1}$ or $g_2$ which are both in $H$, so the representative member from the coset $Z_i(G)$ must also come from $H$.

Renaming $g_1$ and $g_2$ to $h_1 \in Z_i(G) \cap H$ and $h_2 \in H$, we have:

$$h_{1}h_{2}h_{1}^{-1}(Z_i(G) \cap H) = h_2(Z_i(G) \cap H)$$

By the lemma and inductive assumption, we can "expand" this to:

$$h_{1}h_{2}h_{1}^{-1}Z_i(H) = h_2Z_i(H)$$

Which is the definition for $Z_{i + 1}(H)$. So (inductive assumption and) $h_1 \in Z_i(G) \cap H$ implies $h_1 \in Z_{i + 1}$, so $Z_{i + 1}(G) \cap H \leq Z_{i + 1}(H)$.

So it is true for all $i \geq 1$.